# Download a file from a http URL, and than save it on my iPhone for later usage?

Tags: iphone

I am a newcommer to iPhone/Mac programming.Really get stuck at this situation. How to achieve this? NSURLConnection?NSFileHandler?Any clues would be greatly appreciated.Any code snippets would be BIG help.Thanks.

Comment: I remember being stumped by this too way back. But can't remember offf the top of my head the correct method :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip.I am reading that doc.Hope that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest ASIHTTPRequest: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

It seems that NSURLDownload is not available in iOS. Please see the notice below:

> iOS Note: The NSURLDownload class is not available in iOS, because
>   downloading directly to the file system is discouraged. Use the
>   NSURLConnection class instead. See “Using NSURLConnection” for more
>   information.