# Downloading the video file

Tags: iphone, download

How to download a video file from the webserver to application.anyone having tutorial for this or any api is used to download the file.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download a file from a http URL, and than save it on my iPhone for later usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062826/download-a-file-from-a-http-url-and-than-save-it-on-my-iphone-for-later-usage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* Download video */
            NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@", SERVER_URL, @"Videos", serverVideo.videoFileName]];
            NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
            NSString *videoFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseStorePath, serverVideo.videoFileName];
            if ([self storeFile: videoFilePath: videoData]) {
                //.......
            }

- (BOOL) storeFile:(NSString *) path:(NSData *) data {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (data != nil) {
        // Create a file and save the image on filesystem
        if(![fileManager createFileAtPath:path contents:data attributes:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"saveImageError");
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: thanks karim. i used this code to download the zip file and i store the file by static file name. how to get the file by giving the name dynamically.

Comment: You can give the file name Video001, 002 etc, before saving any file, use the NSFileManager class with that file name, if it exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for downloading large files.

Comment: thanks dancreek. r u having any tutorial which is using the ASIHTTP class.